# Verifaction of convergence/divergence exercise

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following assignment in my textbok:

Series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}3^n$ is convergent. Based on that can we conclude that the following series coverge:

- a) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}2^n$
- b) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|c_{n}|2^n$
- c) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(-3)^n$

a) $c_{n}2^n < c_{n}3^n$

$2^n < 3^n$

$2 < 3$

and since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}3^n$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}2^n$ also converges

b)even though $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}2^n$ converges, it doesn't mean that its absolute values converges and there for I can't say anything about whether this seris converges or diverges

c)even though $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}3^n$ converges, that doesn't mean that its absolute value will converge and there for I can't say anything about whether this seris converges or diverges

Are my conclusions right and mathematical rigorous?

Comment: Is $c_n \geq0$? If not, your inequality in a) might not be true.

Comment: @Andrew I suppuose so, since it isn't mentioned

Answer (score 0):

For 1, your logic is backward, but that's not the main problem--the main problem is that this argument fails for $c_n < 0$.

For 2, you are exactly correct--convergence does not imply absolute convergence. As well, it passes the divergence test ($c_n3^n$ must approach $0$, so $c_n$ must approach $0$), so we cannot conclude either way.

For 3, you are right, but for the wrong reason--this series is equivalent to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nc_n3^n,$$ and since the original series converges, we know that $c_n3^n$ must approach $0$. However, we do not know that $c_n3^n$ is a monotonically decreasing series, so we cannot conclude its convergence.

Comment: We of course know the limit of $(-1)^nc_n3^n$, the limit is nulle. Indeed, $-|c_n3^n|\leq(-1)c_n3^n\leq |c_n3^n|$, then $(-1)^nc_n3_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty $

Comment: @idm: I wasn't disputing that. I was disputing the fact that $c_n3^n$ is monotonically decreasing, which is the other requirement for an alternating series to converge.

Answer (score 0):

a) $c_n2^n<c_n3^n$ implies $\sum c_n3^n$ converge work only if $c_n>0$. But here you can't say anything.

b) Your argument is correct.

c) This one converge. Indeed, the two series $-\sum c_n 3^n$ and $\sum c_n 3^n$ converge, $$-c_n3^n\leq (-1)^n c_n3^n\leq c_n 3^n$$ or $$c_n3^n\leq (-1)^n c_n3^n\leq -c_n 3^n$$ for all $n$, and because $\lim_{n\to\infty }(-1)^nc_n3^n =0$.